# Add-in Suddenly Not Supported in Word Online

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-store

I uploaded an add-in to the Office Store last year that uses the following requirement sets and methods:

```xml
<Requirements>
  <Sets>
    <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.2" />
    <Set Name="File" MinVersion="1.1" />
    <Set Name="Settings" MinVersion="1.1" />
    <Set Name="CustomXmlParts" MinVersion="1.1" />
  </Sets>
  <Methods>
    <Method Name="Document.getFilePropertiesAsync" />
  </Methods>
</Requirements>
```

[According to the documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/office-add-in-requirement-sets), all of these should be available in Word Online. Indeed, even the [Microsoft Office Add-in Manifest Validator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-addin-validator) lists Word Online as a supported platform:

[image: My add-in is supported by Word Online, says the manifest validator]

However, recently I noticed that:

- I could not find the add-in on the Office Store from Word Online
- The Office Store page for my add-in does not list Word Online

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your add-in was submitted to the Office Store before any of the requirement sets were released to GA, then your add-in would not have been tagged for compatibility with Word Online. 
If this is the case, then submitting an update to your Office Store listing via the [Seller Dashboard](http://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/) should resolve this issue without additional action on your part. Note that a minor update (e.g. add-in description) would suffice to trigger the revalidation process.

Include in the test notes a link to this question and the validation team will contact you directly should the tagging issue not be resolved up on resubmission.

Comment: Thank you, I have submitted the add-in for re-validation. Based on timestamps in the documentation, I believe the non-GA requirement set at the time (around September 2016) was _probably_ the [Settings API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/settings.md), which became GA after my initial submission.

Comment: The add-in has been re-validated and is showing as available for Word Online in addition to the other platforms, thank you! **For those in the future:** it should be noted that _any_ re-submission definitely requires bumping the version in the manifest, matching the name of the provider on the store with the `<ProviderName>` in the manifest, uploading high-quality screenshots, and calling out any 3rd-party requirements/services on the store page.